# Does't selecting the good value in sql

Tags: php, sql, select, max, record

Hello I have a sql syntax and it always take the last record and doest check the other condition.

```
SELECT * 
from projetstaches ,users,timesheets 
WHERE  `prtTimeSheetId` = ( SELECT MAX(  `prtTimeSheetId` ) FROM projetstaches )  AND usrId = 16 AND timId = prtTimeSheetId
```

I'm working with php and sql but I know this is my syntax is not good.

It's always give me my last record . It's do not take the last record of my user 16 . Cause my last record its for my user 7 . Have any idea why?

So I need to take the last projettime sheet of my user 16

**EDIT ** 
here what look like my data http://pastebin.com/6LBwGtc3

Comment: try OR instead of AND

Comment: its will be worst it will give the last record or the user 16

Comment: Stop using implicit join syntax.

Comment: Difficult to help without more infos about those tables...

Comment: ill edit and add what look my table

Comment: @pc-shooter here we go

Comment: you don't have time sheets for user 16, only for user 7, query should return no rows?

Comment: Sorry I 've modify after the paste bin but don'T worry I have it 16 and 7 but its only return the last for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your query should look like this:

```
SELECT * 
from
    projetstaches
        inner join
    timesheets
        on (timesheets.timId = projetstaches.prtTimeSheetId)
        inner join
    users
        on (users.usrId = timesheets.timUserId)
WHERE
    users.usrId = 16
order by timesheets.timId desc
limit 1
```

To understand how it works I suggest you to play with this query:

1. remove `where` - check result
2. remove `limit` - check result

Comment: yep exacly like that but what is inner join?

Comment: @user3613856 if you want to use several tables in single query - you need to join them somehow, `inner join` means only rows where condition is true and rows exists in both tables, google it for more information, its wide topic